# What's the correct way to fix camera permissions for the newer Android APIs?

Tags: android, permissions, camera, android-permissions

I am a little lost with this new API permission stuff for 21+. My min is 21, target is 23.

I have this in my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false"/>
```

Is this correct? Will people be able to download my app even if they don't have a camera?

Comment: No if the target is 23, then you have to use Runtime Permission.

Comment: Don't you still need the Manifest entries even with Runtime Permission?

Comment: Ofcourse, in Manifest you will have to make entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People can download your app normally. But if your target SDK is 23, you have to implement the Runtime Permission. That means you have to check and request Camera permission at Runtime.

By default the Camera permission is not granted. If you don't check it, your app will crash.

Here is the tutorial of working with Runtime Permission on API 23
[Link](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)

Comment: Do I need to change my Manifest? And the permission in question should just be `android.permission.CAMERA` for runtime, right?

Comment: You don't need to change the `Manifest`. Here is a great tutorial of working with Runtime Permission on API 23 https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: So can I basically return true `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23)`?

Comment: Just read the above tutorial. You will see all information there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use googles easypermission library it is easy to use

in your activity override **onRequestPermissionsResult**  like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        // Forward results to EasyPermissions
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
    }
}
```

and then implement Permission Callback

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        // Forward results to EasyPermissions
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
        // Some permissions have been granted
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
        // Some permissions have been denied
        // ...
    }
}
```

And request pemission of camera like this:

```
@AfterPermissionGranted(RC_CAMERA_PERM)
    public void cameraTask() {
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            // Have permission, do the thing!
            Toast.makeText(this, "TODO: Camera things", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Ask for one permission
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, getString(R.string.rationale_camera),
                    RC_CAMERA_PERM, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }
    }
```

for more code sample check this github repository of easypermission android

[easypemission](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions)

Happy coding